# React. When import function in component function, can i know why it didn`t work hooks setState..?

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks

### I've tried to code splitting for call function when it`s needed.

### so i divided function from component.

```js
//Split.js
const Split = () => {
  return <div>It`s text</div>;
};

export default Split;
```

### It`s work in React Class Component.

```js
//App.js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    Split: null
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    import("./Split").then(({ default: Split }) => {
      this.setState({
        Split
      });
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { Split } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
        {Split && <Split />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here's class component link(working)
https://codesandbox.io/s/code-splitting-1-bbtpe

### But when i changed to Hooks Function Component, It didn`t work..

```js
const App = () => {
  const [split, setSplit] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    import("./Split").then(({ default: Split }) => {
      // console.log(SplitMe());
      setSplit(Split);
    });
  };

  const SplitMe = split;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      {SplitMe && <SplitMe />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and evoked error

#### Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

here's function component link(working)
https://codesandbox.io/s/code-splitting-2-4flbm

#### Can i know what's different class component's setState with function component's setState(hook)?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` and the function returned by `useState` takes two types of arguments:

1. You can set a value directly to it.
2. You can pass it a function which they would call with the previous state as argument.

In the function version, you have imported a function `Split` and used it in:

```
setSplit(Split);
```

Notice that `Split` here is a function and what would apply is the second version of `setState`. It would call the function directly instead of keeping the function as a component. If the component is called with `()`, the type of `<Split />` is invalid (because React can no longer call it, it's not a function)

To get around this, you can store `Split` as an object as you did in the case of the class component.

```
const [split, setSplit] = useState(null);
const handleClick = () => {
  import("./Split").then(({ default: Split }) => {
    setSplit({ Split });
  });
};
const Split = split ? split.Split : null;
```

Now `setSplit` sees a object as an argument and sets it directly.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/code-splitting-2-wcuew)

Comment: what a wonderful resolution!
thanks to your help, i resolve a big problem!
i really appreciate that!!

Answer (score 1):

State can only store `Strings` or `Objects`, and there is no differences between class and hook so this come from the way you implemented your hook.

On component based, you are doing :

```
state = {
    Split: null
};

this.setState({ Split })
```

Using hooks, you need to store your imported function in an object which is what was done by default in the class based component.

To make it work, simply store it this way:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [splits, setSplits] = useState({});
  const handleClick = () => {
    import("./Split").then(({ default: SplitMe }) => {
      // console.log(SplitMe);
      setSplits({ SplitMe });
    });
  };

  const { SplitMe } = splits;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      {SplitMe && <SplitMe />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Your comment on the top is so helpful for me not only belows!
thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved your issue in a different way to the other answers listed.
As Boy With Silver Wings said, 'you can pass it a function which they would call with the previous state as argument'.
A way to get around it is to write a function call in the update and do nothing with the previous state. i.e ()=>SplitMe

So the adjusted code would simply be setSplit(()=>SplitMe)

Have a look at the code sandbox here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/code-splitting-2-0i4v3?fontsize=14

Comment: Awesome!!What a beautiful world! It really helpful thank you!!!:)